# How to get the absolute path of a uploaded file? - Python + Django

Tags: django, python-3.x

This is a snapshot of my web page.

[image]

I am able to get the file name but not the root directory of the file. Is there any way to get it? And also, I want to pass this path to my python code to get some values from excel file.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: are you using `FileField` as the field in your model when you upload ?

Comment: No. I am getting the file name simply through the JavaScript.

Comment: Why are you interested in getting the file path ? It should be easier to access the file itself because django uploads the file to memory. You should include the code handling the file so what u are doing exactly can be seen.

Comment: I need to read an excel file through the upload. and have to pass the data of an column to drop-down of the page.